# Android - RecyclerView vs ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I implement the RecyclerView.

When i check onBindViewHolder it's loading all components and it's taking a long time to become visible with the views.

After i implement ListView and also check the getView, it loads the items much quicker.

My question is: does RecyclerView load all view default or did i wrongly code it?

I am using normal Adapter

For ListView `BaseAdapter`
It's print only 8 items like visible items.

```
ListView listView = (ListView) insertPoint.findViewById(R.id.filePicker);
listView.setAdapter(new FilePickerAdapter(mContext,listView));
```

then

```
    public class FilePickerAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    ListView listView;
    Context mContext;

    public FilePickerAdapter(Context mContext,ListView listView) {

        this.listView = listView;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 100;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final View grid;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)mContext).getLayoutInflater();
            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.filepicker_cell, parent, false);
        } else {
            grid = convertView;
        }

        System.out.println("Position : " + position);

        return grid;
    }
}
```

For RecyclerView    `RecyclerView.Adapter<FilePickerAdapter.FilePickerViewHolder>`

It's print 100 items like All items.

```
RecyclerView recycleView = (RecyclerView) insertPoint.findViewById(R.id.filePicker);
recycleView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(editorView,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));
recycleView.setAdapter(new FilePickerRecycleAdapter(mContext,recycleView));
```

then

```
public class FilePickerRecycleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FilePickerRecycleAdapter.FilePickerViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    public FilePickerRecycleAdapter(Context mContext,RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        this.recyclerView = recyclerView;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @Override
    public FilePickerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.filepicker_cell, null);
        return new FilePickerViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(FilePickerViewHolder holder, int position) {

        System.out.println("Position :" +position);
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 100;
    }

    public class FilePickerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView tvName;
        public View view;
        public ImageView imageView;

        public FilePickerViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            view = itemView;
            tvName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.folder_icon);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so add the code,After that only we can check.

Comment: the problem is in your code. You are misusing `RecuclerView`

Comment: can you please explain me.

Comment: We can't explain anything without a [mcve] of the code you have

Comment: can you explain what exactly you are trying to do?? You have made adapter class,  views.. and at the end you are doing System.out.println . Does this make any sense..

Comment: My question is why list view only print 10 position and recycler print 100 position.

Comment: extra codes added..

Answer (score 0):

"onBindViewHolder" always triggered when the view is visible,maybe your items are fully visible? I printed the position and the result is also the same.

See recycler maybe could help you :)

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Recycler.html